# CSS- and HTML-only tabs not responding properly

Tags: css, menu, tabs

This one really has me confused. It's probably something simple that I've missed, but I sure can't find it...

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9Ftx/) to show you what I'm talking about.

You see originally this had 4 sections, these scrolled through fine with all of the links working correctly. The client has since added 1 more section, now for some reason when I add a further radio link, the whole control of the slide show goes to pot. [See what I mean here.](http://jsfiddle.net/j9Ftx/)

All I've added is an extra link and content area. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? If you erase the below from the jsfiddle you'll see that it works correctly, but with the label for tab 5, it gives up. I'm at a loss... Any help greatly appreciated!

```
<input id="tab-5" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-5" /> <label for="tab-5" class="tab-label-5">POS</label>

<div class="content-5"> <h2>Fullfilment</h2> <p>Whatever your project involves Expressive Print are experienced in delivering it for you. From daily pick and pack requirements to contract packing and bulk despatches we have the ideal space to work in - clean, modern and secure premises with packing teams who are all fully CRB checked, robust stock control systems, comprehensive insurance cover and expertise. This ensures the right things are packed in the right order and sent the right people – simple but critical. Selecting a fulfilment partner who has strong systems with full accountability and customer service resource is vital to ensure your product’s success.</p> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo your **[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9Ftx/5/)**

**Now you just add one line css in your css file**

```
.tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content-1,
.tabs input.tab-selector-2:checked ~ .content .content-2,
.tabs input.tab-selector-3:checked ~ .content .content-3,
.tabs input.tab-selector-4:checked ~ .content .content-4, 
.tabs input.tab-selector-5:checked ~ .content .content-5  // add this line in your css file 
{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    -o-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
    z-index: 100;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-out 0.3s 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease-out 0.3s 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all ease-out 0.3s 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all ease-out 0.3s 0.3s;
    transition: all ease-out 0.3s 0.3s;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j9Ftx/3/)**

Comment: Wow I knew it would be something simple! Thanks so much for spotting that! I also noticed the need for the css below, I have added this and your extra line to the jsfiddle but am still finding the link for print does not work when revisited, any idea why this might be happening? http://jsfiddle.net/j9Ftx/8/ 

.tabs input#tab-5{
 top: 120px;
}

Comment: Actually you can ignore that comment, I've just updated my file as per the jsfiddle and all works fine :) thank you so much for your help! You're a star!

Comment: Hi I'm having another problem with this. The client has just asked for an image to be added to the background, I have done this and it is working fine in Chrome and IE. However in Safari the image is being cut off, please see http://jsfiddle.net/j9Ftx/11/ for what I am referring to. There must be something in the CSS for the tabs that is controlling the width but I can't find what. Thanks for any help

Comment: Thank you very much Rohit :) that seems to have solved the problem with the image, however now the tab is over the text, any idea why? http://creationdev.co.uk/expressiveprint/screenshot.png

Comment: @Ria Used to z-index with position